# How do read text file from server using scala

Tags: scala

How do read text file from server. below are my file structure

scala

main
    src
      scala classes

```
properties
  readme.txt
```

below are my code

filepath = "/properties/readme.txt"

```
val textfilecontent: String= scala.io.Source.fromFile(filepath).getLines.mkString
```

i am getting file not found exception. Thanks in advance

Comment: is properties a directory in your project?

Comment: Yes. Part of my project folder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the properties folder to your resources directory like below

```
resources
  properties
    readme.txt
```

now you read the file using the below snippet.

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile(this.getClass.getResource("/properties/readme.txt").getFile).getLines.mkString
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is working fine. No need of moving to resource directory.i have used below code :  
    val resourcesPath = getClass.getResource(filePath)


    val stopWord = scala.io.Source.fromFile(resourcesPath.getPath).mkString

Answer (score 0):

Paths starting with `/` are absolute paths. You should either provide an absolute path, or remove the `/` if this is the right relative path.